How can I convert YOLOv5 to tflite MICRO using 8-Bit Quantization?
I successfully converted YOLOv5 Nano to tflite using a representative set of images
(Ultralytics export also does that). I can see the scale and zero point for the input and it is fine. I can also ask for float32 input and output and the converter inserts quantize and de-quantize operators -- all is well so far.
However, the output is not correct, and I don't know how can it be correct using 8bit quantization because the BB is given in image coordinates (0..640) and the confidence/probability are given in the range (0..1) in the same output tensor -- and both cannot be represented using the same scale+zero point values.
The general question is how can convert YOLOv5 Nano to TF-lite 8bit quantization?
Risking XY question I would also ask:
How can export the Ultralytics model so the BB will also be in the range 0..1 (relative to image size)?
Thank you!

Solved.
Export using Ultralytics export.py takes care of it.
Coordinates are normalized.
